# Google Map Zoom Changed Event Not Firing

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have download the code from the following link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/291499/Google-Maps-API-V-for-ASP-NET

But Zoom Changed event not firing. Here the snippet

**Code file**

public partial class MapWithZoomLevels : System.Web.UI.Page
   {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    GoogleMapForASPNet1.ZoomChanged += new GoogleMapForASPNet.ZoomChangedHandler(OnZoomChanged);
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        //You must specify Google Map API Key for this component. You can obtain this key from http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html
        //For samples to run properly, set GoogleAPIKey in Web.Config file.
        GoogleMapForASPNet1.GoogleMapObject.APIKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleAPIKey"];

        //Specify width and height for map. You can specify either in pixels or in percentage relative to it's container.
        GoogleMapForASPNet1.GoogleMapObject.Width = "700px"; // You can also specify percentage(e.g. 80%) here
        GoogleMapForASPNet1.GoogleMapObject.Height = "400px";            
    }
}
//Add event handler for PushpinDrag event
void OnZoomChanged(int pZoomLevel)
{
    //pID is ID of pushpin which was moved.
    lblZoomLevel.Text = pZoomLevel.ToString();
}
}
```

**Design**

```
<div>
    <uc1:GoogleMapForASPNet ID="GoogleMapForASPNet1" runat="server" />
<div/>
```